# Account management in storefront for customers is not working

Tags: virtocommerce

The demo site of storefront doesn't provide customers to enter their address for delivery or am I missing something here. Managing it back in the platform is possible. However, it could be better if it is available in storefront having clients to immediately enter their address when managing their account. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have availability to manage personal addresses in the cabinet, it will be accessible only after in the storefront authentification  (sign in).
[image]